In NextJS: How to make dynamic pages re-render on client-side navigation? I've reached a dead end with the client-side Router Cache
I love NextJS and the app router, but I'm stuck with an issue relating to the client-side Router Cache. Here is a simple example that illustrates my biggest problem with caching in NextJS. The docs offer no solution for this dead end, and I have seen many others on the web asking for a solution, but none can be found by me.
I have two routes with UI rendered by server components:
app/page.tsx
import Link from "next/link";

export default function HomePage() {
  const value = Math.random();

  return (
    <main>
      <h1>App router</h1>
      <p>{value}</p>
      <Link href="/other">Other</Link>
    </main>
  );
}

app/other/page.tsx
import Link from "next/link";

export default function OtherPage() {
  return (
    <main>
      <Link href="/">Back</Link>
    </main>
  );
}

By default NextJS caches all route segments. In the example above, NextJS will prerender both routes at build time, and store the HTML in the Full Route Cache. This can be great for static pages, but my HomePage component needs to generate a new random value on every visit.
So I want to opt out of the Full Route Cache. In the docs it simply states that you can do this by exporting dynamic = 'force-dynamic' . As stated in the docs:
"This will skip the Full Route Cache and the Data Cache. Meaning components will be rendered and data fetched on every incoming request to the server. The Router Cache will still apply as it's a client-side cache."
So this opts out of what we could call Static Generation, and makes the page essentially Server Side Rendered. This is what I want: every visit needs to re-render the component. But... "The Router Cache will still apply as it's a client-side cache."
So how do I force a client-side navigation with the  component to skip the client-side Router Cache? The docs state that: "It's not possible to opt out of the Router Cache. However, you can invalidate it by calling router.refresh, revalidatePath, or revalidateTag ".
Router.refresh() is a client-side function as it uses the client-side useRouter() hook. But my component is not a "use client" component, so I cannot use that. RevalidatePath() in my understanding is used to revalidate the cache on-demand. For example when you change content in a CMS, you can use a webhook and call revalidatePath to make sure the next user gets the new content. But this has nothing to do with my component. I simply need to re-render the component on every request, even on client-side navigation.
So ...
TLDR:
how do I make sure that the HomePage component gets re-rendered on every visit, even when using client-side navigation with ?

I just stumbled on this problem too. Did you eventually find a solution?
